# A question on identity in quantified modal logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, modal-logic

One can prove that $a=b \to \Box a=b$ by using the substitution axiom for equality. However, since $\neg a=b$ is not of the form $\alpha_1 =\alpha_2$, I don’t see how to prove $\Diamond a=b \to a=b$, even though I know it’s valid in most modal logics. Is the substitution $[a=b/\neg a=b]$ actually the correct way to prove it, or am I missing something?

I am able to prove this in quantified $ \sf S5$, but it’s valid in system $\sf K$. Any help would be appreciated.

*Edit* I already asked a similar question here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/98888/identity-in-quantified-modal-logic, but the answer doesn’t specifically answer my current question.

Comment: I think the answer is essentially the same as what is discussed in the comments on your philosophy.stackexchange.com question: it depends on whether the interpretation of variables is allowed to change between worlds.